# XAMP opening many port

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am working on PHP and using Xamp. It was working fine earlier, and suddenly opening many ports for APACHE when I am trying reload any page on localhost.
Here is the screenshot how it looks, when I try reload page.
[image]

Comment: @satya i already attached the screenshot

Comment: Seem this thread is old but you could try http://laragon.org/ to help simplify  PHP Development.